# Accidentally added solution to wrong Team Foundation Service project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure-devops

I created a new project, and accidentally added it to the wrong TFS folder.

I went to **Change Source Control** and clicked **Unbind**. It gave this warning and I said okay:

> You are about to unbind one or more of your projects. After this
>   operation, you will no longer be able to access source control for
>   these projects.

But now, when I try **Add solution to source control...** again, it automatically gets added to the wrong TFS project.

I also tried deleting the solution and recreating it, but if I use the name name it still automatically gets added to the incorrect TFS project.

I could just start a new project with a different name, but I'd like to know how to fix this.

How can I change which TFS project I'm using.

Comment: Have you tried, removing the bindings, Closing VS, deleting the *.sou file and restarting VS?

Comment: @DaveShaw Yes, tried doing that with both the `.sou` and `.vssscc` files.

Comment: Try again, and whilst deleting the suo file, edit the SLN file with notepad and remove any "scc" Global Sections. That might work...?

Comment: @DaveShaw There weren't any entries like that in there. I also looked in the `.csproj` file and all of the scc nodes were empty. I was able to figure out how to fix this, but thanks for the troubleshooting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To correct this I had to goto **File** > **Source Control** > **Advanced** > **Workspaces...** and click **Edit** for my account.

That brings up the **Edit Workspace** window, which lists all of the controlled projects, their source control folders and local folders. 
[image: Visual Studio 2012 Edit Workspaces dialog]

From there the paths can be edited or the projects can be removed completely.

Comment: FYI, that's not showing all the controlled projects or anything. It's showing all the folders in the workspace.